# Intersection of a source and destination list with reordering based on the destination list

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I want to return the array of common properties from these two lists.
The intersection is working, but the final reordering does not match the order of properties already present in the destination list.

```cs
private static PropertyInfo[] PropertyIntersection(Item dest, Item src)
{
    List<PropertyInfo> src_props = new(src.GetType().GetProperties());
    List<PropertyInfo> dest_props = new(dest.GetType().GetProperties());

    //Create the intersection
    var ienum = src_props.Select(x => x.Name).Intersect(dest_props.Select(x => x.Name));
    List<PropertyInfo> list = src_props.Where(x => ienum.Contains(x.Name)).ToList();

    // reorder to match order of dest_props
    // How do I order by name?                 
    return list.OrderBy(d => dest_props.IndexOf(d)).ToArray();
}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Just create an array of destination property names. And use the same technique for the names, not the propertyInfos themselves. Something like this `list.OrderBy(d => destinationNames.IndexOf(d.Name)).ToArray();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A problem with your code is that it has a **O(n<sup>2</sup>)** time complexity. Therefore, I suggest using a [HashSet<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1) which has a **O(1)** time complexity for lookups. This results in a query having **O(n)** time complexity.

```cs
var src_props = src.GetType().GetProperties();
var dest_props = dest.GetType().GetProperties();

var srcNames = src_props.Select(p => p.Name).ToHashSet();
var intersection = dest_props.Where(p => srcNames.Contains(p.Name)).ToArray();
```

The `GetProperties` method returns an array which is just fine. There is no need to create lists.

Note that the `Where` extension method does not change the order of the elements. Since we apply it to the `dest_props`, the result will automatically be sorted by this destination array.

---

**Important**:
The documentation for the [Type.GetProperties Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getproperties) says:

> In .NET 6 and earlier versions, the GetProperties method does not return properties in a particular order, such as alphabetical or declaration order. Your code must not depend on the order in which properties are returned, because that order varies. However, starting with .NET 7, the ordering is deterministic based upon the metadata ordering in the assembly.

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick and is really quite elegant.